# Why overachieve in quests?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

Some gathering and hunting quests are finished by delivering a Paw-Pass Ticket when certain conditions are met - say when hunting 2 of a certain monster, or delivering 10 of an item - but you can keep delivering more items or hunting more monsters.

One famous example is the HR6 quest "Coal Hearted", which ends after delivering a staggering 90 Coal, but it can also be finished by delivering a Paw-Pass Ticket that is supplied after delivering 10 Coals. A hunting example would be each of the level 6 Deviant hunts, which you can end by delivering a Paw-Pass Ticket after hunting two of the Deviant monster in question.

While I can see why sometimes you'd want to hunt a large number of monsters for various reasons, I don't know why you'd waste time on delivering more account items.

What happens when you deliver more items or hunt more monsters than you strictly need to finish the quest?

Comment: Can you provide an specific example of a quest that gives you a Paw-Pass Ticket after you have gathered a specific number of items? Every quest I've seen requiring a number of items or points completes automatically once you've reached that number.

Comment: @Kadima Hunt-a-thons require a minimum of 2 kills and then the paw pass appears in the crate, but you can stick around and keep hunting.

Comment: @Rapitor Yes, but I'm asking specifically about the gathering quests mentioned, because the OP states they already understand why a person would hunt more large monsters but is curious why a person would continue a gathering quest beyond the requirement.

Comment: @Kadima I've added an example for each kind of quest. I know I've seen some of the gathering kind in the village, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delivering account items gives you a reward of money and caravan points. Any provided beyond the requirement for the quest provide those bonuses immediately, where if you hold them until the quest completes the zenny and points are awarded during the mission rundown, where you can collect mission rewards and palico collected items.

The main benefit to delivering during the mission is if your bag is full, you can drop them off for the bonuses and then continue your hunt for more items, including more account items that provide zenny/points.

Delivering them after you have delivered the items required by the quest gives no real benefit, they just provide the option so they don't have to write code blocking that functionality during that small period of time.

EDIT: I've looked into the "Coal Hearted" example, and it seems that changing the number of times and amount of items you deliver changes the quest rewards you can receive. That mission is often used to farm timeworn charms and just how many it gives you in mission rewards is affected by your deliveries. I probably should have realized that, seeing as the Hunt-a-thon quests give you more monster parts if you kill more monsters before running out of time or delivering a Paw-Pass Ticket.

EDIT 2: I found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/4y4yxo/main_reward_c_on_kiranico_and_mhgen_db/) that Hunt-a-thons and certain gathering quests have rewards based on how far beyond the minimum requirement you go. Apparently there's an entire bracket of rewards specifically for going the extra mile.

> Row C comes from quests where the main target is delivering X+ of an item and a paw pass, or hunting 2+ of a monster and a paw pass, like Hunt-a-thon quests. You get extra slots for exceeding the minimum requirement. Every 2 large monsters past the minimum adds a slot, every 10 items past the minimum adds a slot.

[This example](http://mhgen.kiranico.com/quest/village/3.14-cancer-of-the-dunes) is not exactly a gathering quest, but it behaves a similar way and can show the extra rewards available for going beyond the minimums. Any quest with Reward C is a quest that you can go beyond the minimums to increase your reward, much like any quest with a Sub Reward will have a subquest that makes those rewards available upon completion.

Comment: No, I'm talking about delivering, say, 45 Coals when the quest only needs 10, and then ending the quest. You do not get zenny and point rewards for items you deliver as a quest objective.

Comment: Does the game allow you to overdeliver like that? I thought it provided a cap that prevents that. Otherwise, I believe those extra deliverables are lost and you gain no benefit for them.

Comment: Please read my question, I've specified how some quests work.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I found an answer to your question and put it in the edit.

Comment: If you can find some information about Hunt-a-thons or other gathering quests, I'll accept this.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Hopefully Edit 2 is satisfactory.

Comment: Pretty much perfect.